# Jquery Zebra list odd even display after filtering data.

Tags: jquery, css, filter

I have a problem displaying "zebra" list after filtering results.
I have a zebra list which display perfect here is the code:

```
$('ul li:odd').addClass('zebra_odd');
$('ul li:even').addClass('zebra_even');
```

The problem comes when I filter that list an input like this:

```
  $('input').keyup(function() {                   
    var textboxVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();   
    $('ul li').each(function() {                    
    var listVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase();     
      if(listVal.indexOf(textboxVal) >= 0) {      
        $(this).show();                        
      } else {
        $(this).hide();                         
      }
```

i.e. on the list I have this values: `a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3.` The list display the values on zebra rows perfect, but if I filter the data i.e. "a" it will show me a1, a2, a3 all in white background, it kept the old odd, even values. Thanks

Comment: Why dont you have the css for odd and even `ul li:odd`, `ul li:even` on your style sheet instead of a new class?

Comment: Something like this in the css? li:nth-child(odd) { color:black }
li:nth-child(even) { color:white }  ?? I'm new to programming not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: Check my answer, it does what you want. CSS ones wont work properly after you filter/hide elements.

Comment: @Neal, as he is filtering the elements, `:nth-child(odd or even)` wont work for this case. as Those will take hidden elements into account too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to Update `odd,even` classes after filtering the elements like this

```
function setOddEven() {
    $('li:visible:odd').removeClass('odd even').addClass('odd');
    $('li:visible:even').removeClass('odd even').addClass('even');
}
$(function() {
    setOddEven();
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        var textboxVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('ul li').each(function() {
            $this = $(this); // cache the object for better performance
            var listVal = $this.text().toLowerCase();
            if (listVal.indexOf(textboxVal) >= 0) {
                $this.show();
            } else {
                $this.hide();
            }
        });
        setOddEven();
    });
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/asnCv/2/)

Dont forget the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, or it will take hidden elements into account and hence wont work properly.